# Cosmos DB Array Query Doesn't Work in .NET SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm attempting to get all distinct category values used in a container, where categories is an array of strings.

Looking at the Cosmos DB SQL docs, I've constructed the following query which works in the Emulator when I execute the SQL and returns an array of distinct categories as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c IN s.categories
```

Results in

```
[
    "Running",
    "Rugby",
    "Icon"
]
```

However, if I use the same query via the Cosmos .NET SDK I get an error

> "Identifier 'session' could not be resolved."

Why would this query work in the Emulator but not via the SDK? Am I doing something wrong or this is an issue with the SDK?

Sample data:

```
{
"name": "Sample Entity",
"description": "<p></p>",
"startDateUtc": "2020-07-13T19:10:00Z",
"endDateUtc": "2020-07-13T20:00:00Z",
"categories": [
    "Running",
    "Icon"
],
"id": "h3foyhfk0a3betj1",
"dateCreated": "2020-07-15T06:33:57.9406583Z",
"lastUpdated": "2020-08-13T17:04:18.6182079Z" }
```

The SDK Code:

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c IN s.categories");
var results = new List<TEntity>();
            
var resultSetIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<TEntity>(query, requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) });
while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
      var response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
      results.AddRange(response);
      if (response.Diagnostics != null)
      {
           _logger.LogTrace($"\nQueryWithSqlParameters Diagnostics: {response.Diagnostics}");
      }
}

return results;
```

Comment: Using the same collection? Is your SDK version using your local emulator?

Comment: try changing s to c for container alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `, requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)`.

[image]

Then you will get result. There maybe wrong in `requestOptions` when you use.

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c IN s.categories");
var results = new List<dynamic>();

var resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(query);
while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    results.AddRange(response);
    if (response.Diagnostics != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nQueryWithSqlParameters Diagnostics: {response.Diagnostics}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I didn't even think about the partition key adjusting the query. Would there be a way to do the same query limited to only one partition? In this case I don't want a cross-partition query.